# Import OBJ with textures

Tags: import

So up until recently I have been editing 3D models using the built in windows 10 app 3D builder, but I decided to give blender a go because of its good reviews. When 3D builder exports as an obj it puts the obj file, an mtl(I think), and *all of the textures*. When I import the obj to blender, not surprisingly, it drops all the textures and makes the object white. How do I import the textures along with the obj?

Comment: Hi, I'm not completely familiar with this but I think .mtl just carry the information for the shader where to apply texture on the model. You will have to export the colors as textures (save them separately as jpg or so) to use them as a texture. There is a difference between material and texture. Obj can create .mtl even if there isn't any texture to export. Its just a thought.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531

Answer (score 2):

OBJ (Wavefront) file itself only stores geometry data, it does not keep anything regarding materials or textures. So you can't import .obj file with texture or materials.You can try .fbx file.